# How can I reduce glare on my computer monitor?

Tags: anti-glare, eye-strain

I use a 19 inch LCD monitor and sit with my back to the windows. During some times of the day I get reflection from the sun - however moving my desk isn't an option. I've tried looking on Amazon for anti-glare devices, but none with good reviews fit my screen. What can I do to reduce the glare on my computer?

[image]

Comment: I wonder if wearing polarizing sunglasses would help...

Comment: curtains! on the bright side, it isn't one of those newfangled glossy screens.

Comment: grow a huge afro ! :-)

Comment: @Flimzy I have some prescription sunglasses which I think are polarized. I tried that and it's harder to read the screen and my paperwork. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go with a good old standby: A filter.

[These are probably](http://solutions.3m.com/wps/portal/3M/en_US/ergonomics/home/products/computerfilters/) the very best, but you can find less-good ones, which are cheaper.

You can also check out [this eHow article](http://www.ehow.com/how_113856_rid-screen-glare.html) (the hood idea #4, while ugly, may work for your problem):

> If you can't avoid overhead light, you can construct an anti-glare hood for your monitor by taping together several sheets of black cardboard and using them to frame your monitor screen.

Comment: Update: I ordered a 3M EF200XXLB and it's working great! :)